# Integer range literal in groovy becomes an arraylist with one element which is the integer range

Tags: arraylist, groovy, int, range

It was strange to me to find out that

```
3 in [1..7]
```

in Groovy returns `false`.

I have checked the class type  of `[1..7]` and turns out that it is an `ArrayList` containing one element and that one element is of type `IntRange` containing my 7 elements, hence  `3 in [1..7][0]` returns `true`.

Whats going on? I was thinking that `[1..7]` should be an instance of `IntRange`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct [range definition](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Range.html) in Groovy is:

```
1..7
```

E.g. you can test it in groovysh:

```
groovy:000> 1..7
===> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

When you define it as `[1..7]` you actually created a nested range list in a array list, that's why expression `3 in [1..7]` returns `false`.

```
groovy:000> 3 in 1..7
===> true
groovy:000> [1..7].dump()
===> <java.util.ArrayList@4a elementData=[1..7] size=1 modCount=1>
groovy:000> [1..7][0].dump()
===> <groovy.lang.IntRange@2b from=1 to=7 reverse=false inclusive=true modCount=0>
groovy:000> 3 in [1..7]
===> false
groovy:000>
```

In some cases you may see expression like:

```
(1..7)
```

but this one is an equivalent of `1..7` - parentheses just set expression boundaries and they don't change expression type like `[1..7]` does.